# Insert missing values in column at all levels of another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, distinct, cross-join

I have been working with some big data in SQL/BigQuery and found that it has some **holes in it that need to be filled with values in order to complete the dataset**. What I'm struggling with is **how to insert the missing values properly**.

Say that I have multiple levels of a variable (`1, 2, 3...` no upper bound) and for each of these levels, they should have an `A, B, C` value. Some of these records will have data, others will not.

Current dataset:

```
level value data
1     A     1a_data
1     B     1b_data
1     C     1c_data
2     A     2a_data
2     C     2c_data
3     B     3b_data
```

What I want the dataset to look like:

```
level value data
1     A     1a_data
1     B     1b_data
1     C     1c_data
2     A     2a_data
2     B     NULL
2     C     2c_data
3     A     NULL
3     B     3b_data
3     C     NULL
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of the distinct `level`s with the distinct `value`s and a `LEFT` join to the table:

```
SELECT l.level, v.value, t.data
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level FROM tablename) l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM tablename) v
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON t.level = l.level AND t.value = v.value
ORDER BY l.level, v.value;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=557435f7fbe8eb0e3c96f65285a15ff0).

Comment: This worked for me, what I wasn't quite getting conceptually was creating the lists from `DISTINCT` values and then doing a `CROSS JOIN` before joining my original dataset back in.

Answer (score 0):

We can use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with the help of a calendar table:

```sql
INSERT INTO yourTable (level, value, data)
SELECT t1.level, t2.value, NULL
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level FROM yourTable) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM yourTable) t2
LEFT JOIN yourTable t3
    ON t3.level = t1.level AND
       t3.value = t2.value
WHERE t3.data IS NULL;
```